# PyCharm возможно ли проверять орфографию не везде?

Tags: pycharm, настройка

Есть 2 варианта того, где вылезают `Typo` ошибки в `PyCharm`е:

1. Я печатаю условный `print('Helo World')` и он выдает `Typo` на `Helo`. Эти `Typo` мне нравятся, и хотелось бы их оставить.
2. Я печатаю про какой-нибудь `subprocess.Popen(r'my-autor --gife-me-tis ass-mycommands')`, и мне тут же сыпется куча `Typo` ошибок на то, на что я повлиять никак не могу.

Могу ли я сделать как-то, чтобы хотя бы на самых распространённых (встроенных в Python?) возможностях там, где не нужно, он бы не `Typo`? Вот, к примеру, проверять на `Typo` содержимое `subprocess`овских функций как бы не нужно совсем.

PS Я видел [Вот эту](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383554/how-to-avoid-the-spell-check-on-string-in-pycharm) и ряд подобных тем о том, как вырубить `Typo` вообще. Но интересно сделать это только частично, и, чтобы те же `print()`, `input()` и остальное подобное он бы проверял.

Comment: Поставьте курсор на строку `'my-autor...'`, нажмите `Alt + Enter`, далее выберите `Inject language or reference`, далее выберите `Shell script`. Теперь IDE будет воспринимать эту строку как текст на языке `Shell script`. Подойдет ли вам такой вариант решения проблемы?

Comment: Ну, это частности. Т.е. это мне каждое место надо так протыкивать? Мдя, код конечно становится красииииивый....
Но в целом оно как бы работает, да.